# Best way to store journalling data in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am creating a journalling app where users can input some text every day in a structured fashion by answering questions. I am wondering what the best way to store my data is.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
data = [
    ...
    "2021-04-19": ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3"], 
    "2021-04-20": ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3"], 
    ...
]
```

Does this sound like a sensible thing todo?

I am sorry if this sounds like silly question but I've never done this before and couldn't find the "best answer" online anywhere.

Comment: is there gonna be exactly 1 question every day? and where do you wanna store? backend or local db ?

Comment: @GauravRoy, there is going to be 1 question every day but with 3 answers. The question will be "What went well today?" and then you have to answer 3 times. I don't care where I store the data, I think locally on the device is the easiest and most pragmatic option right now. I was thinking AsyncStorage.